# How to capture with sngrep -O an rotate files by hour?

Tags: shell, tcpdump, strftime

I was using `tcpdump` to capture 1 files per hour and save filename with `%H` to have a file rotation of 1 file per hour.
Now I'm trying to use `sngrep -O file%H.pcap`, but it saves always same `file%H.pcap` file literally.

How to name them `file01.pcap, file02... file24.pcap?`

I wanted to use with `"timeout 1h sngrep... "` To capture only 1h.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date` command.

```
sngrep -O "file$(date +%H).pcap"
```

Example:

```
  $ printf "%s\n" "file$(date +%H).pcap"
  file20.pcap

  $ date
  Sat Feb  9 20:16:29 IST 2019
```